# updateOne and findOneAndUpdate on MongoDB not working properly in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
exports.dashboardUpdateNote = async (req, res, next) => {
    var updateNote = {
        "title": req.body.title,
        "body": req.body.body1,
    }
    await Note.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.note_id }, { $set: updateNote })
        .then((Successful) => {
            console.log('Successful: ', Successful)
        })
    return res.redirect('/dashboard')
}
```

It redirected but no changes(updates) occure.
Then I made this change in the code(Adding:  { upsert: true }):

```
exports.dashboardUpdateNote = async (req, res, next) => {
    var updateNote = {
        "title": req.body.title,
        "body": req.body.body1,
    }
    await Note.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.note_id }, { $set: updateNote }, { upsert: true })
        .then((Successful) => {
            console.log('Successful: ', Successful)
        })
    return res.redirect('/dashboard')
}
```

It redirected and the changes(updates) occured, but when I click the (note) which I have updated to view it it gives this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)     
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:624:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:149:14)       
    at done (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1035:10)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)     
    at View.render (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\hp\NODE\Notes\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
```

But when I click a note which I never updeted to view it no error occurs and the note appears.
(I forgot to write that the note which must be updated didn't updated actually, it added another new note, so the notes increases one after every updating.  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `await` and `then` blocks and do not have any error handling so you don't know if there was an error in saving the document. The actual error you are getting is when to try to send a response after you send a response, typically outside of a block scope you don't account for or haven't returned from.

The `findOneAndUpdate` method takes an update document as the second argument so just pass the `updateNote` object and mongoose will update the `title` and `body` properties for you.

A finished function might look like this:

```js
exports.dashboardUpdateNote = async (req, res, next) => {
   try{
      console.log(req.body); //< make sure you have parsed data in req.body
      const updateNote = {  //< use const instead of var
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body1,
      }
      const doc = await Note.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.note_id}, 
         updateNote, 
         {new: true}  //< return the updated document
      );
      if(!doc){ //< doc will be null if no document was found
         return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'No document found.'
         });
      }
      // Document was updated so return to dashboard
      console.log('Successful: ', doc)
      return res.redirect('/dashboard')
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
      // Handle the error
      return res.status(500).json({
           message: 'Error on server.'
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code and the result: {"message":"No document found."}. Although the code ( console.log(req.body) ) results: ({ title: 'Z Node.js Tutorial', body1: ' Node.js is an open-source server environment\r\n ', note_id: '6589dd6d7c4f1bc33799132a' } ) . And it matches the note which is selected. I have another question why do the notes that I have updated give an error when I click their? Do I have to delete their?

Comment: If you are getting `{"message":"No document found."}` that means the `findOneAndUpdate` returned a null because it didn't find a document with `_id` equal to `req.body.note_id`. Are you sure you have document with that `_id`? Do you have mongsh or compass installed to check? Can you post your schema?

Comment: Yes, I have verified its existence several times. Anyway, I think I should change my study of this project because I think it is old and contains a lot of codes that did not work for me until I modified them.

Comment: const NoteSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        // required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
})

Comment: @Hadi it can happen that you add data, then modify your schema and the data no longer matches the types in your schema. For example you have `_id` as a string in your schema but it may be an `ObjectId` in the database.

Comment: I changed the code , and it upadted the note, but when I click the updated note it gives this error :   if (element._id == req.params.id) {
                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: The change is :
        const theNote = await Note.find({})
            .then((notes) => {
                notes.forEach(note => {
                    if (note._id == req.body.note_id) {
                        console.log("note", note)
                        const doc1 = Note.updateOne({ _id: req.body.note_id },
                            updateNote,
                            { new: true }  
                        );

Comment: Thank you very much jQueeny, I correct the schema and it's right now with no errors. I couldn't cast a vote for your answer because my repution is less than 15.